# Can't connect to Azure Kubernetes cluster from internet

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-nsg, ingress-nginx

I have an ingress-nginx ingress for my Kubernetes service.
If I curl the external IP from inside the cluster, like from a pod such as this `kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu -- bash`, I get the result I expect.
If I curl from the internet, It times out. What could be the problem?

Resources online have pointed me to check my firewall and NSG settings. I see one of my NSGs has an explicit exception for the IP chosen by the ingress-nginx ingress, which seems to update automatically. Is there a way to see if there are other firewalls and network security groups between my AKS cluster and the internet?

This problem began after updating from kubernetes 1.19 to 1.22

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the AKS cluster and recreated it. this resolved the issue but was obviously very destructive.